# Grunt create png from div with text

Tags: javascript, jquery, gruntjs

I'm looking for a grunt package which can convert an html element with text to a png image.
For example I might have a div like this:

```
<style>
div{font-family:"Roboto";line-height:30px;font-size:25px;width:50px;}
</style>
<div>this is a text which will display over multiple lines when visible on screen</div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NaLPmE

So far I haven't been able to find a package which is able to convert this. Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: you may want to try html2canvas,i don't think grunt can do that, the page needs to be rendered to create acurate png

Comment: @madalinivascu hmmm... it sounds logical, but grunt is also able to take screenshots of a webpage with a delay to catch js animations, that's why I thought it should be able to this as well

Comment: [grunt-webshot](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-webshot) might meet your requirement, however I haven’t used it myself. If you add an `id=“foo”` attribute on the `<div>` then perhaps you can utilize the [captureSelector](https://github.com/brenden/node-webshot/#options) option.

Comment: ...also take a look at [grunt-screenshot-element](https://github.com/smallmultiples/grunt-screenshot-element).